# Can't run Android Studio Emulator on AMD - ERROR: x86

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, amd-processor

I've a Ryzen 7 3700x CPU (Windows 10) and few days ago I've run Android Emulator (X86) with success. After installing Virtualbox and VmWare now I can't run emulator.

Here's the error:

*

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is
>   properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: GVM is not
>   installed on this machine More info on configuring VM acceleration on
>   Windows:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
>   If you are using an Intel CPU: please check that virtualization is
>   enabled in the BIOS and that HAXM is installed and usable. Note: if
>   Hyper-V or Credential Guard is enabled, the emulator will not work
>   with HAXM. See
>   https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105#issuecomment-470927735 for
>   info on how to disable Credential Guard. If you are using an AMD CPU
>   or need to run alongside Hyper-V-based apps such as Docker, we
>   recommend using Windows Hypervisor Platform.General information on
>   acceleration:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

*

I have turn on Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform (of course bios virtualization is ON) ..what I can do?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After plenty of research I found a solution for my ryzen system:
[image]
(source: https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105)

Turn this windows setting on and somehow it will work. Don't ask me why.

I also found an official new amd driver: [https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/...](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html)
But I was already using the new driver. It did only work after I switched the setting above.

Comment: There is a lot going on in https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/105, not sure if you solution is the only thing to change. But good hint anyway, so +1.

Comment: I install the official new amd driver and it works!!!!!!!! thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

https://finsterbt.com/switch-between-hyper-v-and-virtualbox-on-windows-10/

> VirtualBox, VMware Workstation, and VMware Player do not work on machines with Hyper-V enabled.
>
> To resolve this conflict, create a new boot menu option that reboots the computer with Hyper-V temporarily disabled.

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Disable Hyper-V"
bcdedit /set  $GUID     hypervisorlaunchtype off
bcdedit /set  {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

[image: Ryzen Android Emulator]

Answer (score 0):

I spent +10hrs on trying different things to make this work.
Funnily enough when I finally enabled hyper V and reinstalled android studio (removing appdata files as well prior) it worked again. I just leave this comment here for the future troopers with Ryzen CPUs.
Im on ryzen4500U with Win11 Home.